# How to express xy(x^4 - y^4) sqrt{(1+(x^2+y^2)^2)} in terms of u and v given that u = 2xy and v = x^2-y^2?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am stuck in working out the term (x^4 - y^4). Though (x^4 - y^4) can be written as (x^2 + y^2) (x^2 - y^2), but I have no idea for the next step. hope somebody can help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $x^4 - y^4 = (x^2 - y^2)^2+2(xy)^2 = v^2+u^2/2$

Comment: Thanks for your response. But v^2 = x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^2

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution ?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=\sqrt {(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

From $$u=2xy$$ we get $$y=\frac{u}{2x}$$ so $$v=x^2-\frac{u^2}{4x^2}$$ and we get the equation $$0=4x^4-4x^2v-u^2$$ which can be solved for $x$.